# Integration using partial fractions formula is unexplained in my text

Tags: integration

I am trying to do integrals using the partial fraction method and I see this bit of confusing text:

[image]

How can I even check if this work is correct? This feels like rote memorization and I don't understand the concept.

I'm a tad unsure of what to do here or where the formula in the solution section came from. Why is there a $Bx + C$ in the numerator when this formula is simply $B$:

How do I even check to see if this formula for computing integrals is correct? This seems like rote memorization no?

[image]

Comment: The crucial point here is that $x^2+4$ is irreducible over $\mathbb R$, therefore we have to leave this factor as it is but instead of choosing $B$ as nominator we need to chose $Bx+C$. Similiar would occur if we got an irreducible third order polynomial, then we have to chose $Bx^2+Cx+D$ and so on. Sadly speaking I can only say that decision like that are quite common but I am still not sure why at all.

Comment: You can actually decompose it, if you allow for compex numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to memorise the method, I would suggest you the following :

Consider  $$\dfrac {2x^2-x+4}{x^3+4x}. $$
Our aim is to decompose this into partial fraction. We can do the following manipulation :
\begin{align}
\dfrac {2x^2-x+4}{x^3+4x}&=\dfrac {2x^2-x+4}{x (x^2+4)}\\
&=\dfrac{x^2+4-x+x^2}{x (x^2+4)}\\
&=\dfrac{x^2+4}{x (x^2+4)}+\dfrac {x^2-x}{x (x^2+4)}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac {x (x-1)}{x (x^2+4)}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac {x-1}{x^2+4}
\end{align}

---

> How can I even check if this work is correct?

Compute $\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac {x-1}{x^2+4}$ and see whether you're getting  $\dfrac {2x^2-x+4}{x^3+4x}$ or not.

Hope this helps.